# Sql query to fetch only few records from 1 column based on Condition and show/display it separately using Select query

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, radgrid

EDITED:

In my database table, I have 4 columns *ID* ,*Action*, *Name* and *DateTime* with below records:

```
Action         Name      DateTime
-------------------------------------
Submit         AA        'date time'
Update         BB        'date time'
Save           CC        'date time'
Match          DD        'date time'
Submit         EE        'date time'
Submit         FF        'date time'
Update         GG        'date time'
Approve        HH        'date time'
Approve        II        'date time'
Update         JJ        'date time'
Match          KK        'date time'
Save           LL        'date time'
Match          MM        'date time'
etc                      'date time'
etc                      'date time'
```

These records can be repeated multiple time.

I want to select the Name and DateTime from above Table that has Action = Submit and Action = Update; into two separate columns using select query(Just like we get the data using select query).

Example queries:

```
SELECT 
    Name as SubmitterName, DateTime AS SubmitterDateTime
FROM 
    [tbl_WorkflowHistory]
WHERE 
    Action = 'Submit' 

SELECT 
    Name as UpdateName, DateTime AS  UpdateDateTime
FROM 
    [tbl_WorkflowHistory]
WHERE 
    Action = 'Update'
```

Only thing is I want to show the records of both the query together but in 4 separate columns, like below format:

Output needed:

```
SubmitName    SubmitDateTime    UpdateName    UpdateDateTime
-------------------------------------------------------------
    AA        'datetime'          BB          'datetime' 
    EE        'datetime'          GG          'datetime'
    FF        'datetime'          JJ          'datetime'
    etc                           etc
```

Under "SubmitName" column, all Names shall come that has Action=Submit along with there respective DateTime in SubmitDateTime column. Similarly, under "UpdateName" column, all all Names shall come that has Action=Update along with there respective DateTime in UpdateDateTime column. I dont know how to write this query, its just sample to explain my requirement.

And after selecting records like above Output, using sql query, I have to display it in a RadGrid in which data coming inside "SubmitDateTime" column have to show separately (Date separate , Time separate) in 2 different columns of RadGrid i.e., SubmitDate, SubmitTime. Similarly for "UpdateDateTime" i.e., UpdateDate, UpdateTime; as described as Below:

```
SubmitAction    SubmitDate    SubmitTime    UpdateAction    UpdateDate    UpdateTime
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Submit          'date'        'time'        Update          'date'        'time'
Submit          'date'        'time'        Update          'date'        'time'
Submit          'date'        'time'        Update          'date'        'time'
etc
```

I hope I made my requirement clear. Please let me know how to do this. I am using SQL Server database. Please reply. Thanks in advance

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.  (2) What is your question?  You seem to want some sort of pivot, but I don't understand the relationship between the input data and the desired results.

Comment: I think your sample data is incomplete, I think you miss some kind of id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thank you for the reply. I am using **SQL Server Database**. And yes the 1st column is the ID (which is auto generated) column, 2nd ACTION and 3rd DateTime. In "Action" column, there are actions recorded. Now, through query I want to fetch the 2 different "Actions" i.e., Submit & Update; into two separate columns along with their date. Like for Action=Submit, I want to fetch all the "Submit" action into a column named as "SubmitAction" with their respective date&time in another column. Similarly for Action=Update. Please reply how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below query works fine as per my requirement:

```
 Select * FROM
 ( 
 SELECT RequestID, Action, UserName as SubmitterName , CreatedDate AS  SubmitterDateTime
 FROM [tbl_WorkflowHistory]
 Where Action = 'Submit') as A

 Join

 (SELECT RequestID, Action, UserName as UpdateName , CreatedDate AS  UpdateDateTime
 FROM [tbl_WorkflowHistory]
 Where Action = 'Update') as B 

 ON A.RequestID=B.RequestID
```

Thank you every one for the reply and help.

Answer (score 1):

If the data in the **DateTime** column is space separated then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2(SubmitAction,SubmitDate,SubmitTime)
SELECT Action,left(DateTime,locate(' ',DateTime)-1),substr(DateTime,locate(' ',DateTime)+1) FROM TABLE_1;
```

It should work,if I've understand your question properly.. If you need something else,please elaborate your question. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I dont want to insert the data. I only want to select the data from Table that has 3 columns: ID, Action, DateTime (structure of this table is defined in my posted question) Now I want to select Action = Submit and Action = Update along with DateTime into two separate columns (Just like we get the data using select query).

Comment: **Example:** *Select Action as SubmitAction, DateTime as SubmitDateTime , Action as UpdateActon DateTime, DateTime as UpdateDateTime from Table1 where Action='Submit' and Action='Update'  *.

Under "SubmitAction" column, all Action=Submit should come along with there respective DateTime in SubmitDateTime. Similarly, under 
"UpdateActon" column all Action=Update should come along with there respective DateTime in UpdateDateTime.
I dont know how to write this query, its just sample to explain my requirement.

Comment: And after selecting records like above, I have to display it in RadGrid in which data coming inside "SubmitDateTime" column have to show in 2 different columms of RadGrid i.e., SubmitDate, SubmitTime. Similarly for "UpdateDateTime" data. I hope my requirement is clear. Please reply

Comment: Try this:  
 
`SELECT Action,left(DateTime,locate('     ',DateTime)-1),substr(DateTime,locate(' ',DateTime)+1) FROM TABLE_1 WHERE Action = "Submit";`  

Similarly for update change "WHERE Action = "Submit"" to "WHERE Action = "Update""  
Hope this will work.  

Yes the question is clear now. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had again updated my posted question please do have a look. And when I try your suggested solution I get this error: `'locate' is not a recognized built-in function name.` Please reply

Comment: Are you using MySQL workbench to run the query? `locate` is a built-in function to that. Or in Oracle 11g and so on

Comment: No, I am using SQLServer to run my query. But its showing this error that I told. My query is: ` SELECT Action,left(CreatedDate,locate(' ',CreatedDate)-1),substr(CreatedDate,locate(',',CreatedDate)+1) 
 FROM [tbl_WorkflowHistory]
 WHERE Action = 'Submit';` and I get error in this line: `locate(' ',CreatedDate)-1),substr(CreatedDate,locate(',',CreatedDate)+1)` Please reply

Comment: Please replace the `locate` with `CHARINDEX` and give it a try. I don't have SQLServer installed so can't test. My Bad

Comment: I guess `CHARINDEX` is working, but now it is pointing error at this line: `substr(CreatedDate,CHARINDEX(',',CreatedDate)+1) `
Same Error: 'substr' is not a recognized built-in function name. ; for 'substr'

Comment: Oh ok.. you need to replace `substr` with `SUBSTRING` for SQL server. Sorry forgot to mention in the previous comment..

Comment: I changed my query as:  SELECT Action,left(CreatedDate, CHARINDEX('',CreatedDate)-1),SUBSTRING(CreatedDate,CHARINDEX(',',CreatedDate)+1) FROM [tbl_WorkflowHistory] WHERE Action = 'Submit';  but was getting this error: `The substring function requires 3 argument(s).` again I changed this line as: SUBSTRING(CreatedDate,CHARINDEX(',',CreatedDate)+1, CreatedDate) ; now getting this error: `Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.` Please reply

Comment: Please tell me your format of the `DateTime` column with a valid date-time

Comment: This is my DateTime format: 2015-08-04 00:00:00.000 and its data type is: datetime . What shall I change in my query ? Please do review my posted question again, I made a change in my requirement. Please reply accordingly.